# X and Y value from getBoundingClientRect wrong when used with Css Translate

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

Within React, I'm animating the transition from many pictures to one when a specific picture is selected.

I'm using the following css for the animation based on the original clicked image's x and y position. It is hard coded right now. However, the values seem to be off when put into css' translate and I cannot figure out why.

I absolute positioned a div with the same values and that is correct. But , the starting values of translate are not what I'm putting in.

```
@keyframes move-image {
    from {
        transform:  translate( 383.125px, 7.998px) scale(1);
    }
}

.animation {
   animation: move-image 6.6s;
}
```

Here is a link. The animation css is in the css tab. https://codepen.io/nickjsdevelope1/pen/QoWEPV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

translation consider the intial element position to translate the element, it behave as offset. it doesn't translate the element to a particular position. The same logic apply when you position an element using top/left. top/left are relative to the containing block of the positionned element in case it's an absolute/fixed element.

In both cases, it's about an offset from an origin but the origin is not the same for each one.

To better understand here is a translation applied to different element with the same values:

```css
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  transform:translate(50px,50px);
}
.box1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  transform:translate(50px,50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box1">

</div>
```

Both element are offsetted from their original position by `50px` on both X and Y axis.

When using position and top/left both will overlap because they have the same containing block so they are offsetted by the same values from the same point.

```css
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
.box1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box1">

</div>
```